# Regex is not working in RegularExpression Annotation

Tags: .net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have applied client side validation using **RegularExpression** Annotation in ViewModel.

The validation is **GroupName** should *startwith either **TPDC_** or **DMK_** with atleast one more letter*

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Group Name is required")]
        [RegularExpression("^(TPDC_|DMK_)+", ErrorMessage = "Group Name should begin with TPDC_ or DMK_")]
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
```

But the regex used is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to match a string that starts with `TPDC` or `DMK` and then has a `_` followed with one or more letters, you may consider using

```
^(TPDC|DMK)_[A-Za-z]+$
```

Or, if after `_`, there may be any characters, but a letter is required to appear somewhere, you may use

```
^(TPDC|DMK)_[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z].*
```

See [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/rKVf8q/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/rKVf8q/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(TPDC|DMK)` - either `TPDC` or `DMK`
- `_` - an underscore
- `[A-Za-z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters (`\p{L}+` will only work on the server side!)
- `[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z].*` - any 0 or more chars other than ASCII letters (`\P{L}*` is the Unicode equivalent of `[^A-Za-z]*` that will only work on the server side), an ASCII letter, and then any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to repeat the group with the alternation. If you want the following letter to be A-Z you could add a character class after it. The underscore might be moved to after closing the group.

```
^(?:TPDC|DMK)_[A-Z]
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non caputure group

  - `TPDC|DMK` Match TPDC or DMK
- `)` Close group
- `_[A-Z]` Match an underscore followed by a char A-Z

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3aTPDC%7cDMK%29_%5bA-Z%5d&i=TPDC_A%0d%0aDMK_A%0d%0aTPDC_%0d%0aDMK_&o=m)

Or if you want to allow any letter from any language you could use `\p{L}` instead

```
^(?:TPDC|DMK)_\p{L}
```